# Tangent to a line is the line itself. But, def. of tangent touches at 1 point?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Does a line have a tangent line?  It would be the line itself.  The slope of the tangent line is the slope of the line itself.  This is verified by a derivative example.   But, isn't the definition of a tangent line "a line that touches at one point"?  Doesn't the tangent line to a line touch at infinite points?

$f(x) = 2x+1$

$f'(x) = 2$

This implies a line does have a tangent, right?

Comment: No, that is not a definition of the tangent line.

Comment: The definition does not care about other points.

Comment: That's only the definition of the tangent line TO A CIRCLE.   To a function, the tangent line is just the line going through that point that shares the slope.    It can touch in plenty of other places, even everywhere.

Comment: A tangent can be a curve; why else would geometricians hold forth on, for example, two mutually tangent circles? Would not any curve to which a given line is tangent then be a tangent to that line? I admit the impossibility, though, of two straight lines being mutually tangent in the ordinary sense.

Comment: The tangent line at a point $x$ is the limit of the line between two points on the curve, as the two points get closer to $x$.

Comment: This is a great question. I think I see where you're coming from, as "touches at a point" is _the_ description usually given. But what you've come upon by yourself is a great reason _not_ to define it that way! This is emblematic of a general pattern in mathematics and explains why definitions can sometimes appear convoluted: the simplest description needs to be edited for a few wrinkles ("let's not define [1 as prime](//ncatlab.com/show/too+simple+to+be+simple)", and many more).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so simple to define what is a tangent straight line to a curve.
Your definition ''the line that touch at one point'' can work only if the curve is a conic section ( so it is represented by a second degree equation), but also for a simple curve as $y=x^3$ you can see that all the straight lines that are intuitively tangent at some poin, meet the curve at another point, and the only line that ''touch at one point'' is the line $y=0$ that really is a tangent, but  through the curve just at the point of tangency.

And you can also easily find functions that has the same line as an ''intuitive'' tangent at more than one point (as a simple exemple: $y=\sin x$ with the lines $y=\pm1$).

So a good definition of tangent can be done only at the some time as the definition of derivative, using a limit. In words:

> The tangent line is the limit position of a secant line when the two
>   points of intersection coincide.

Developing this intuition we come to the classical definition of the slope of the tangent as:
$$
m=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)
$$

Now, if the curve is a stright line, this definition can also be used and, yes, the tangent to a stright line is the same stright line.

Comment: Ok, so tangent to a line is a line, and tangent doesn't mean "hits at one point".

Comment: But this limit definition implies the 2 secant points never touch.  That is not a tangent, it is still technically a secant.

Comment: Technically the line passes always between two points, and is this the motif why it's always well defined, but the limit process is such that we can reduce the distance between such points as little as we want ( this is what means $h\rightarrow 0$).

Comment: But, I don't think that is a tangent line then.

Comment: For a discussion about the definition of a tangent line you can read :http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Hasse/07468342.di020721.02p01112.pdf

Comment: Emilio, thanks for posting that.  I am so glad someone actually felt the need to write an entire paper on this little quibble!!